# Not able to use bcrypt in matching passwords in angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

When I register with email and password in my angular app I succeed. However, when I try to login I get an error. On the back end of my Angular App which is being served by Node and MongoDB I keep getting the following errors:

```
C:\Users\my_name\Documents\Sites\css-wx\api\api.js:47
        if(err) throw err;
                ^
 Not a valid BCrypt hash.
 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here are my node js files the first one the app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./models/User.js');
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
/* Use the custom service if you do not want to use JWT Simple */
//var jwt = require('./services/jwt.js');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

  next();
});

app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var user = req.body;

  var newUser = new User({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  });

  newUser.save(function(err) {
    //res.status(200).json(newUser);
    createSendToken(newUser, res);
  })
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  req.user = req.body;
  var searchUser = {
    email: req.user.email
  };
  User.findOne(searchUser, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err

    if (!user)
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: 'Wrong email/password'
      });

    user.comparePasswords(req.user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) throw err;

      if (!isMatch)
        return res.status(401).send({
          message: 'Wrong email/password'
        });

      createSendToken(user, res);
    });
  });
});

function createSendToken(user, res) {
  var payload = {
    sub: user.id
  }

  var token = jwt.encode(payload, 'shhh..');

  res.status(200).send({
    user: user.toJSON(),
    token: token
  })
}

var monitors = [
  'Monitoring',
  'Map',
  'Event List',
  'Waterplant'
];

app.get('/monitors', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(401).send({
      message: 'You are not authorized'
    });
  }

  var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  var payload = jwt.decode(token, "shh..");
  if (!payload.sub) {
    res.status(401).send({
      message: 'Authentication failed'
    });
  }
  res.json(monitors);
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/csswx');

//console.log(jwt.encode('hi', 'secret'));

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('api listening on ', server.address().port);
});
```

Here are my node js files the first one the User.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
//var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String
});

UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  var user = this.toObject();
  delete user.password;
  return user;
};

UserSchema.methods.comparePasswords = function(password, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, callback);
}

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;

  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      user.password = hash;
      next();
    })
  })
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: It looks a lot like you delete the password hash before saving to the database.

Comment: Oh yeah I see what you mean thanks